# Consuming Signal R service in Desktop application

Tags: winforms, push-notification, signalr, signalr-hub, duplex

I am new to SignalR, I want to develop a service using SingalR API’s and Host as selfhost\IIS, now my doubt is How can I consume these message in Client side my client application will be Windows(Desktop) applications. 
    Main intention is to send Notification from SignalR service to Clients. I would like to know is this achievable.

Please share any tutorials link or similar projects URL

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is use .Net events , to wrap the SignlR client functions and connect to the desktop application call backs . like so :

```
public class Client
{
    public delegate void OnReciveMessage(Object message);
    public event OnReciveMessage MessageRecivedEvent;

    public void ReciveMessage(Object message)
    {
         if (MessageRecivedEvent != null)
         {
              MessageRecivedEvent(message);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can connect to a Signal R hub from webclient or winformsclient.

Useful information on this links:

- [SignalR Chat App in WinForm With Remote Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476404/signalr-chat-app-in-winform-with-remote-clients)
- http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host