# C# windows service subscribed to webserver

Tags: c#, popup, windows-services, webserver

I'm working on an intranet website. 
All users should get desktop popups from the webserver whenever something new is posted on the website.

I was looking to make my own windows service that would subscribe to the server ( Making use of something like SignalR ) and then this service would show a simple popup notifying the user whenever the server sends out a message.

But instead of building this myself i was wondering if something like this isn't already out there. I've been looking around a bit but couldn't find anything.

I'm mainly a web developer and have never built a windows service or C# desktop application so i would prefer using some existing code.

Does anyone know of such a thing ?

Comment: you don't have to make it that complicated. Just query your db for new entries or altered data from the windows service and display the info through windows  in the taskbar icon area - service icon

Comment: You don't need windows-service. Create standard Winforms application with "NotifyIcon" component and you win. Showing forms from WindowsService is [1 super-complicated or [2 bad designed (when service is allowed using UI).

Answer (score 2):

For building a Windows Service try Top Shelf: http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/
In general it is easy as one, two, three...

```
public class TownCrier
{
    readonly Timer _timer;
    public TownCrier()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(1000) {AutoReset = true};
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine("It is {0} and all is well", DateTime.Now);
    }
    public void Start() { _timer.Start(); }
    public void Stop() { _timer.Stop(); }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>                            
        {
            x.Service<TownCrier>(s =>                   
            {
               s.ConstructUsing(name=> new TownCrier());
               s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());         
               s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());          
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();                       

            x.SetDescription("Sample Topshelf Host");   
            x.SetDisplayName("Stuff");                  
            x.SetServiceName("Stuff");                  
        });                                             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm working on an intranet website. All users should get desktop
>   popups from the webserver whenever something new is posted on the
>   website.

using **timer** is not a good technique over here as updates are not guaranteed in particular interval or session .but you can take that as an option based on the need.

> I was looking to make my own windows service that would subscribe to
>   the server ( Making use of something like SignalR ) and then this
>   service would show a simple popup notifying the user whenever the
>   server sends out a message.

**Yes** exactly like a chat application that would frequently have messages and users get a pop up.[**ASP.NET SignalR**](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications. Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

[image]

> But instead of building this myself i was wondering if something like
>   this isn't already out there. I've been looking around a bit but
>   couldn't find anything.

**References** for SignalR [Link1](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/signalr-messaging-with-console-server-and-client-web-client-wpf-client/),[Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315938/Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign),[Link3](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/672433/Real-time-Notifications-with-SignalR)

[image]

> I'm mainly a web developer and have never built a windows service or
>   C# desktop application so i would prefer using some existing code.

Making `C#` desktop or windows service is not a big deal as you already are a **programmer**.Some existing codes for updations pop up is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265751/Application-Auto-update-via-Online-Files-in-Csharp).

Answer (score 0):

for the signalr Server side, I would suggest you use a C# winform.

for the client side, you can use JavaScript inside any html file to 'receive' the message from the signalr Server, then you can popup an alert message or whatever you want, however, in this case you have to make sure the users are browsing that html file in a browser, otherwise the message won't be received.

there's no ready code since signalr support different types of servers as well as different types of clients, I believe you need to write your own code.  Actually Signalr is quite easy to use, write your own code may be faster than using the others.

Comment: The popup should be displayed by a service, not from a browser. The users need to get the message even if no browser is open.

Comment: in this case you can build Services for the client side, but then the message received cannot interact with your original intranet Web pages.

Comment: I know, this is ok. I'm mainly looking for something that can already do this ( doens't need to use SignalR, just need to be able to subscribe to a webserver and show a simple popup with some text )

Comment: you know Web server is idle without receiving any http request, so I think you need to find solutions using other technology such as signalr, or msmq, or socket connection, or may be you can simply send emails to clients if your clients email support push notification.

Answer (score 0):

This question: [SignalR Chat App in WinForm With Remote Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476404/signalr-chat-app-in-winform-with-remote-clients) looks like it might point you inthe right direction. Specifically this article:

https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/signalr-messaging-with-console-server-and-client-web-client-wpf-client/

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use DesktopToast: https://github.com/emoacht/DesktopToast
or Growl: http://www.growlforwindows.com/